# How to append Vue Editor values in Form Data - FIXED

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 'vue2-editor', so good working. I want this values send post with formData,

How can I capture the data in it?

Thanks for Helps..

My Editor Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <uax-editor id="editor"></uax-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

export default {
  components: {
    "uax-editor": VueEditor
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

My Form Example..

```
<form id="formData" @submit="submitForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
     <app-editor class="mt-1"></app-editor>
   ...
</form>
```

This is my Form. Inputs and Images working with FormData, i need editor values :)

[image]

---

My codes now working, thanks for [Alireza HI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527086/alireza-hi)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <uax-editor id="editor" :value="editor" @input="val => $emit('update:editor', val)"></uax-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

export default {
  components: {
    "uax-editor": VueEditor
  },
  props: {
    editor: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

and...

```
<app-editor class="mt-1" :editor.sync="editor"></app-editor>
```

and...

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: '',
      editor: ''
    };
  },
  components: {
    "app-editor": ThisEditor,
    "app-single-update": ThisSingleImageUpdate
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formData"));

      formData.append('desc', this.editor);
      console.log(this.editor);

      for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ", " + pair[1]);
      }

      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/uax_designers_addOne',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to send your data from Form and handle them inside your Editor when the user submit ?

Comment: I want to send the data entered by the user with the editor with form data. @MenaiAlaEddine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the form using `js` and have a `data` which is your `editor` value.

Also you need to pass the variable to your component using the `sync` syntax.
Read more about it here:
[Vue Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

So your components would become like this:

Editor Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <uax-editor id="editor" :value="editor" @input="val => $emit('update:editor', val)"></uax-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

export default {
  components: {
    "uax-editor": VueEditor
  },
  props: {
    editor: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Form Example:

```
<form id="formData" @submit.prevent="sendData">
   ...
     <app-editor class="mt-1" :editor.sync="editor"></app-editor>
   ...
</form>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    editor: '',
  }),
  methods: {
     sendData(){
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("editor", this.editor);

      let response = await fetch('/your-url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      });
      let result = await response.json();
      alert(result.message);
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for help. I'm copied your codes, finally this.editor again send null.

formData.append('desc', this.editor);
console.log(this.editor); // Null.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Because you are passing a data(here `editor`) as a prop and you can not change and modify a `prop`. That's the reason that `sync` has been added to vue. It helps you to `emit` a function to change the prop using the parent adjusting.

Comment: @UğurcanAlyüz I forgot to bind the elements(I mean adding `:` to `:value="editor"` and `:editor.sync="editor"`. I have changed the code. Try the new one.

Comment: Also I change this line: `@input="val => $emit('update:editor', val)"`

Comment: While it was empty before, now it comes undefined. I think we went one step further. :)

Comment: @AlirezaHI Sorry, I have one question. My GET API have Description, i write description value to Editor. ( <app-editor class="mt-1" :editor.sync="item.designer_desc"></app-editor>) Write, not problem. And i again update this value, editor null. Why?